# T-SQL count items by adding and removing

Tags: sql, t-sql, variables, counter

In SQL Server 2008, I have Table1 and I want to get the output as shown in expected output.
Every time Action 'Count' occurs, it add/removes all relevant items and show the total.
Assuming all items begin with 0 count.

[image]

Many Thanks.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1([Time] [smalldatetime] NULL,[Action] [nvarchar](10) NULL,[Item] [nchar](50) NULL)
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:02','Count','Apple')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:03','Count','Banana')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:04','Count','Mango')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:05','Count','Black Berry')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:06','Count','Orange')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:07','Add','Apple')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:08','Add','Banana')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:09','Add','Mango')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:10','Remove','Banana')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:11','Add','Banana')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:12','Add','Mango')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:13','Add','Mango')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:14','Add','Mango')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:15','Remove','Mango')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:17','Count','Apple')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:18','Add','Banana')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:19','Add','Banana')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:20','Remove','Banana')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:21','Add','Apple')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:22','Add','Mango')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:23','Add','Apple')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:24','Add','Mango')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:25','Remove','Apple')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:26','Count','Mango')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:27','Add','Apple')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:28','Add','Banana')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:29','Remove','Apple')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:30','Remove','Banana')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:31','Add','Banana')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:32','Add','Mango')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:33','Count','Banana')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:34','Add','Banana')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:35','Add','Apple')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:36','Remove','Mango')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:37','Add','Apple')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:38','Add','Mango')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:39','Count','Apple')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:40','Remove','Apple')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:41','Remove','Banana')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:42','Add','Banana')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:43','Add','Mango')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:44','Count','Banana')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:45','Remove','Banana')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:46','Remove','Apple')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:47','Remove','Mango')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:48','Add','Apple')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:49','Add','Mango')
insert into Table1 values('2009-08-22 20:34:50','Count','Mango')
```

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you.

Comment: Agreed. As it is, this is a work description, not a question.

Comment: I wish I knew what the best way to solve this. I will appreciate even a hint on how to solve this.

Comment: After changing Time to datetime format from smalldatetime, it works fine. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with a left outer self join as shown below
However the results produced are different from what you have shown probably because you made some calculation mistakes. Anyway try similar approach.

```
select a.time,a.item,
SUM(case 
when b.action='Add' then 1
when b.action='Remove' then -1 
else 0 end)
from table1 as a
left join table1 as b
on a.item=b.item
and b.time<a.time
where a.action='Count'
group by a.time,a.item,a.action
order by 1
```

Comment: Thanks Joesph for quick response. You are right, there was a calculation error. This is big help in itself. Can you please advise how to have record every time there is a count for any item.